# How to perform clustering of lat/lon data points

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

My preferred algorithm is DBSCAN in scikit-learn. I am not sure however if (and how) to incorporate the radius in addition to latitude and longitude that I use already. My second question in how to compute the centers of the new clusters. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

DBSCAN uses an epsilon radius query. This is where you use latitude and longitue.

I don't know if scikit-learn allows you to use arbitrary distances though. I've seen a [blog post](http://www.vitavonni.de/blog/201410/2014102301-clustering-23-mio-tweet-locations.html) on using OPTICS (the successor of DBSCAN) to cluster 23 million tweets using latitude and longitude; but it used ELKI not scikit-learn.

DBSCAN doesn't use centroids. So you don't need to compute them on the sphere at all.
In fact, **centroids do not make sense for DBSCAN**. They may be *outside* the cluster, if it is not convex; and DBSCAN can find non-convex clusters. Consider a city with a lake in the center. The centroid may be right in the lake. Or a city in a bay - the centroid will be inside the bay then. The centroid of the bay area (san francisco, Oakland, ...) probably is near treasure island... etc.

Answer (score 0):

one way to calculate centroid,is to make a sum of  each  each cluster's longitudes(sum of each point's longitude) and calculate the mean value,this will give you a rough longitude for your centroid.Do the same thing for latitude.
Here is a good [example](http://geoffboeing.com/2014/08/clustering-to-reduce-spatial-data-set-size/) that was fair in my point of viw